# In Pandas, need to take only a specific number of dates per user

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have df containing usersidid(int) and date(datatime):

```
 usersidid  date
1   1   2017-01-05
2   2   2017-01-02
3   3   2017-01-04
4   4   2017-01-02
5   1   2017-01-01
6   2   2017-01-03
7   3   2017-01-02
8   1   2017-01-04
9   2   2017-01-05
```

I have parameters called @timeframe, @MinDates.
What I need is to check **per usersidid** if from today to (today-@timeframe) there's enough different MinDates in the dataframe, if not the program need to exit. I'll show:

Example A-

```
@timeframe = 5
@MinDates = 1
today = 2017-01-05
```

in this case the result:

```
usersidid   date
1   1   2017-01-01
2   1   2017-01-04
3   1   2017-01-05
4   2   2017-01-02
5   2   2017-01-03
6   2   2017-01-05
7   3   2017-01-02
8   3   2017-01-04
9   4   2017-01-02
```

Example B-

```
@timeframe = 5
@MinDates = 2
today = 2017-01-05
```

in this case the result:

```
  usersidid date
1   1   2017-01-01
2   1   2017-01-04
3   1   2017-01-05
4   2   2017-01-02
5   2   2017-01-03
6   2   2017-01-05
7   3   2017-01-02
8   3   2017-01-04
```

Example C-

```
@timeframe = 5
@MinDates = 3
today = 2017-01-05
```

in this case the result:

```
 usersidid  date
1   1   2017-01-01
2   1   2017-01-04
3   1   2017-01-05
4   2   2017-01-02
5   2   2017-01-03
6   2   2017-01-05
```

Example D-

```
@timeframe = 5
@MinDates = 4
today = 2017-01-05
```

in this case the result: not enough different dates within the timeframe, exit program

Example E-

```
@timeframe = 3
@MinDates = 2
today = 2017-01-05
```

in this case the result (fixed thanks to Ted Petrou):

```
  usersidid   date
1    1      2017-01-04
2    1      2017-01-05
3    2      2017-01-03
4    2      2017-01-05
```

My idea in general:

```
agg1 = df[today >= timedelta(days=@dataframe) + df.date]
agg2 = agg1.groupby(['usersidid'], as_index=False, sort=False)['date'].countunique().rename(columns={'date': 'NumOfDifferentDates'})
agg3 = agg2[agg2.NumOfDifferentDates >= @MinDates]
result = df[df.usersidid.isin(agg3.loc[:, 'usersidid'])].reset_index(drop=True)]
if result.empty() exit(0)
```

I haven't run it yet so I don't know if it works and because I'm a very new beginner in Pandas I'm sure there's a more elegant way to do it that i would love to hear about.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function that takes in three arguments, `today`, `timeframe` and `mindates` and first uses boolean indexing to filter the dataframe down to just the rows that are within the timeframe. From here you can group by each `useridid` and filter out the groups that don't equal or exceed `mindates`.

```
def find_dates(today, timeframe, mindates):
    prev = today - np.timedelta64(timeframe-1, 'D')
    df_new = df[df.date.between(prev, today)]
    return df_new.groupby('usersidid').filter(lambda x: len(x) >= mindates).sort_values(['usersidid', 'date'])

today = pd.to_datetime('2017-01-05')
```

Now you can call your function with your specific arguments.

```
find_dates(today, 5, 1)

       usersidid       date
5          1 2017-01-01
8          1 2017-01-04
1          1 2017-01-05
2          2 2017-01-02
6          2 2017-01-03
9          2 2017-01-05
7          3 2017-01-02
3          3 2017-01-04
4          4 2017-01-02

find_dates(today, 5, 2)

   usersidid       date
5          1 2017-01-01
8          1 2017-01-04
1          1 2017-01-05
2          2 2017-01-02
6          2 2017-01-03
9          2 2017-01-05
7          3 2017-01-02
3          3 2017-01-04

find_dates(today, 5, 3)

   usersidid       date
5          1 2017-01-01
8          1 2017-01-04
1          1 2017-01-05
2          2 2017-01-02
6          2 2017-01-03
9          2 2017-01-05

find_dates(today, 5, 4)
# returns empty dataframe
```

I did not understand how your last result with timeframe=3 and mindates=2 works. Both useridid 1 and 2 have two rows within the last three days.

```
find_dates(today, 3, 2)

   usersidid       date
8          1 2017-01-04
1          1 2017-01-05
6          2 2017-01-03
9          2 2017-01-05
```

Comment: 1. You're absolutely right, I had an error in the  timeframe=3 and mindates=2 exmple, should have ended the way you wrote.
2. Is there a way to do this without using lambda? too much on the performance.
Thanks for your help!